# Can AWS Codecommit show moved or renamed files

Tags: aws-codecommit, git-mv

I use AWS codecommit for code review, and am wondering if it possible to get it to show moved or renamed files, for easier reviewing.

At the moment, it is very difficult to review teammates work, because if ever they rename or move a file, there will be hundreds of lines of diff.

I appreciate that someone will probably say:

> *You should move all the files in one commit, and call it "moved files", and then simply review commit-by-commit, ignoring that one.*

**This won't work** because I cannot control the actions and habits of dozens of co-workers, nor would I want to attempt to compel management to enforce such behaviour.

---

I just did a test run, and I have all but confirmed that this seems to be the case, whether you are reviewing a commit or a pull request.

The following commands were used to perform the test:

```
git checkout main
git checkout -b test
git mv README.md README_MOVED.md
git commit
git push
```

And they resulted in this output:

[image: AWS codecommit does not show renames or moves]

Has anyone managed to configure AWS Codecommit to show moved/renamed files, or is this tool just not fit for purpose, and we should swap to a different one?